# Editor : automatically map the id of a contained object

Tags: gwt

I have a service which enables the user to search some Item s with many criteria.

I have a class which represents those criterias:

```
public class ItemFilter{

  private Integer idCountry;
  private Integer minPrice;
  private Integer maxPrice;
  ...

  //Getters and Setters
}
```

Then, I use an Editor to edit the properties of this filter :

```
public class ItemFilterEditor extends Composite implements Editor<ItemFilter> {

  ComboBox<Country> country;
  NumberField<Integer> minPrice;
  NumberField<Integer> maxPrixe;
  ...

}
```

The problem here is that I need a ComboBox to enable the user to select a Country but the class ItemFilter only accepts the id of the country.

Question : Is there a way to automatically set the idCountry of the ItemFilter when the editor is flushed?

The only solution I found is to create an intermediate class and do some mapping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your editor implement `ValueAwareEditor` and do the mapping in `setValue` and `flush`.

```java
public class ItemFilterEditor extends Composite implements ValueAwareEditor<ItemFilter> {

  @Editor.Ignore ComboBox<Country> country;
  NumberField<Integer> minPrice;
  NumberField<Integer> maxPrixe;
  ...

  private ItemFilter value;

  @Override
  public void setValue(ItemFilter value) {
    this.value = value;
    // select the item in country with ID equal to value.getIdCountry()
  }

  @Override
  public void flush() {
    this.value.setIdCountry(/* get the ID of the selected country */);
  }
}
```

Or alternately use a `LeafValueEditor<Integer>` to do the mapping:

```java
public class ItemFilterEditor extends Composite implements Editor<ItemFilter> {

  @Editor.Ignore ComboBox<Country> country;
  final LeafValueEditor<Integer> idCountry = new LeafValueEditor<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Integer value) {
      // select the item in country with ID equal to value
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
      return /* get the ID of the selected country */);
    }
  };

  NumberField<Integer> minPrice;
  NumberField<Integer> maxPrixe;
  ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I edited the question to expose the solution using LeafValueEditor. Don't hesitate if there are some possible improvements to do.

Comment: I was on mobile when I first replied. I just edited my answer with sample code of what I had in mind.

Comment: I removed my solution : yours looks more concise :)
I still have a question about ValueAwareEditor : Are you supposed to map all values in setValue() or just those that are not handled by the Editor?

Comment: Only those that are not handled by the Editor. Otherwise you'd be a `LeafValueEditor`.